# Detect righ click on CKEDITOR focus handler

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

When attaching focus handlers to multiple CKEDITOR's in a loop:

```
for(i=0; i<editors.length; i++){
    ....
    CKEDITOR.instances[editors[i]].on('focus', handleFocus);
};

var handleFocus = function(){
  console.log("this= ",this);
};
```

How can i get the actual "event" also in my handleFocus function, so that I can skip any right click (context menu) clicks, using this existing function for skipping right clicks inside the editor:

```
var isRightClick = function(event){
        switch (event.which) {
            case 1: return false;  // Left Mouse button
            case 2: return false;  // Middle Mouse button
            case 3: return true;   // Right Mouse button
            default: return false; // Strange Mouse!
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the provided event data:

```
var handleFocus = function(ev){
  console.log("event= ", ev);
};
```

That way you can get the info about the editor on which the event is fired, cancel the event, get the original event data, ...

This applies to any event listener that you attach in CKEditor event model.